# SVN Commit of a changelist with a new folder and new file fails: E155011 file out of date E160013: File not found:

Tags: svn

I am using SVN version 1.7.14 on Linux.

I added modified files and a new folder with a new file to a change list.

```
--- Changelist 'my-changelist':
A       trunk/new_folder/new_file.txt
M       trunk/existing_file0.txt
M       trunk/existing_file1.txt
M       trunk/existing_file2.txt
M       trunk/existing_file3.txt
M       trunk/existing_file4.txt
M       trunk/existing_file5.txt
M       trunk/existing_file6.txt
M       trunk/existing_file7.txt
M       trunk/existing_file8.txt
```

I already ran **svn update** and there are no pending conflicts however I still keep getting the following errors when trying to commit this change list to my remote SVN repository:

```
svn commit -m "Updates" --changelist my-changelist
Adding         trunk/new_folder/new_file.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file0.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file1.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file2.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file3.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file4.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file5.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file6.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file7.txt
Sending        trunk/existing_file8.txt
Transmitting file data .svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File '/home/username/svn/project/trunk/new_folder/new_file.txt' is out of date
svn: E160013: File not found: transaction '14544-bjr', path '/X2/project/trunk/new_folder/new_file.txt'
```

Seems like it has problem commiting the new folder and file as it cannot find the new file on the remote repository. Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?

Comment: You should update your SVN client. SVN 1.7.x is outdated. The most recent version is 1.14.x.

Comment: The SVN client I have is on a Linux AWS instance.  I don't have permissions to update it